# How do I reference something I've referred to, but not directly quoted. Or do I?

Tags: citations, reference-request

I'm writing a report and I've used a website for some of my research. I haven't directly quoted anything from the website but you can tell that's where I got my information from if you know what I mean.

I'm required to use APA 6th referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question, "should I reference X?", is almost always yes.  It is proper to reference sources used in your research even if you don't use direct quotes and regardless of referencing style.

Comment: Thank you I just wanted to know. Should I do it at the end of the paragraph?

Comment: Yes.  You should use an in-text citation (in addition to a full reference at the end of the paper) after a paragraph that contains information from the cited source.